# Swift: play videos in turns from a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, video

I am working on an app where I need to play videos from a FOR loop i.e. play local video against the string provided in each iteration of the loop.

The problem is when I call the playVideo() func from the loop, all the videos play simultaneously. I want them to play one after the other and then dismiss the AVPlayerLayer i.e. remove from the superlayer.
When a single video is played, the playerLayer gets dismissed but in case of more than one, the playerLayer is intact.

How to make them play one after other?

I have read about using dispatch queues, but don't know much about them.

code :

```
func parseString(string: String){
    var stringArray = string.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    logTextView.text = ""
    for i in 0..<stringArray.count{
        playVideo(stringArray[i].lowercaseString)
    }
}

var player: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

// video player

private func playVideo(name: String) {
    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType:"mp4") else {
        print("file not found")
        return
    }
    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    //        playerController.player = player
    self.playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view!.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)
    self.player!.play()
 //   playing = true

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.playerDidFinishPlaying(_:)),
                                                     name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player.currentItem)
}

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Video Finished")
    self.playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
  //  playing = false
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do not give your code as a link and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which pointing   out your issue here.

Comment: replaced the link with the code. Is the problem understandable?

Comment: Actually, I don't know about the ios, It's just review of your first post and just save you from down votes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use for loop then. Take an `int i = 0`, then increase (`i++`) until `i` becomes more than `stringArray.count`

```
if (i == stringArray.count) { 
    //end 
}
```

call the function, where you are doing the above execution, from `playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification)`.
Hope this will help.

Comment: there's a lag in one layer being removed and other being added. How to make the transition seamless?